# Redirect from login URL

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

i am trying to redirect from login page when there is session. is there any option in class `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint` below my spring xml. kindly give your inputs to achieve this

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <beans:bean id="springSecurityFilterChain"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
        <filter-chain-map path-type="ant">
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/template/img/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/template/css/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/template/js/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/template/misc/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/js/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/tiles/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/resources/img/**"
                filters="none" />
            <filter-chain pattern="/**"
                filters="
            securityContextPersistenceFilter,
            logoutFilter,
            authenticationProcessingFilter,
            exceptionTranslationFilter,
            filterSecurityInterceptor" />
        </filter-chain-map>

    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="exceptionTranslationFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationEntryPoint" ref="authenticationEntryPoint" />
        <beans:property name="accessDeniedHandler" ref="accessDeniedHandler" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <!-- <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login.jsp?error=entryPoint" 
            /> -->
        <beans:property name="loginFormUrl" value="/login" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="accessDeniedHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl">
        <!-- <property name="errorPage" value="/login.jsp?error=access_denied" 
            /> -->
        <beans:property name="errorPage" value= "/loginfail" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="authenticationFailureHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/loginfail" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    <beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
            <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/frame_design" />
        </beans:bean>
    </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="filterSecurityInterceptor"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor">
        <beans:property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager" />
        <beans:property name="accessDecisionManager" ref="accessDecisionManager" />
        <beans:property name="securityMetadataSource">
            <filter-security-metadata-source
                path-type="ant" id="securityDefinitionSource">
                <intercept-url pattern="/frame_design*"
                    access="ADMIN" />

            </filter-security-metadata-source>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="logoutFilter"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter">
        <beans:constructor-arg value="/logout" />
        <beans:constructor-arg ref="logoutHandler">
        </beans:constructor-arg>
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="logoutHandler"
        class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.SecurityContextLogoutHandler">

    </beans:bean>
    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider">

        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="authenticationProvider"
        class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="employAuthDetailsService" />
        <beans:property name="passwordEncoder" ref="passwordEncoder"/>
            <beans:property name="saltSource" ref="saltSource"/>


    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id ="passwordEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder" >
 <beans:constructor-arg value="512"/>
 <beans:property name="iterations" value="1024"/> 
 </beans:bean>
 <beans:bean id="saltSource"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource">
 <beans:property name="userPropertyToUse" value="username"></beans:property>

 </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="employAuthDetailsService" class="com.app.myapp.security.UserDetailsServiceImp">
    </beans:bean>


        <beans:bean id="accessDecisionManager"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
            <beans:property name="decisionVoters">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:ref bean="roleVoter" />
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>
        <beans:bean id="roleVoter"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleHierarchyVoter">
            <beans:property name="rolePrefix" value="" />
            <beans:constructor-arg ref="roleHierarchy" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="roleHierarchy"
            class="org.springframework.security.access.hierarchicalroles.RoleHierarchyImpl">
            <beans:property name="hierarchy">
                <beans:value>
                    ADMIN
<!--                    ADMIN > ROLE_OWNER -->
<!--                    ROLE_OWNER > ROLE_DISTRIBUTOR -->
<!--                    ROLE_DISTRIBUTOR > ROLE_RESELLER -->
<!--                    ROLE_RESELLER > ROLE_USER -->

                </beans:value>
            </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: I think your officially using every feature of spring security!

Comment: just my sample to see things in Spring Security

Comment: So your trying to default to a page after login, regardless of url requested?

Comment: only for login URL after login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing a already logged in user from accessing the log-in page again.

- Most cleanest approach:
  You could implement a Filter (`HandlerInterceptor` or `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`), that redirects the already loged in user
- More a hack: use `<sec:authenticate>` in the login page to trigger an java script that redirect the user, when he is already logged in.

My LoginPageRedirectInterceptor:

```
public class LoginPageRedirectInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    private String[] loginPagePrefixes = new String[] { "/login" };

    private String redirectUrl =  "/";

    private UrlPathHelper urlPathHelper = new UrlPathHelper();

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response,
                             Object handler) throws Exception {

        if (isInLoginPaths(this.urlPathHelper.getLookupPathForRequest(request))
                && isAuthenticated()) {                
            response.setContentType("text/plain");
            sendRedirect(request, response);
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }


    private boolean isAuthenticated() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext()
                                             .getAuthentication();
        if (authentication == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {
            return false;
        }
        return authentication.isAuthenticated();
    }

    private void sendRedirect(HttpServletRequest request,
                              HttpServletResponse response) {

        String encodedRedirectURL = response.encodeRedirectURL(
                           request.getContextPath() + this.redirectUrl);
        response.setStatus(HttpStatus.SC_TEMPORARY_REDIRECT);
        response.setHeader("Location", encodedRedirectURL);
    }

    private boolean isInLoginPaths(String requestUrl) {

        for (String login : this.loginPagePrefixes) {
            if (requestUrl.startsWith(login)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input @Ralph that works fine for me. But my question is how can i redirect from login url to a default url when login url is directly given in the browser if a session of role is in browser

Comment: Ah: you want to prevent an already logged in user from accessing the login page again? - is this what you asked for?

Answer (score 0):

See: [SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler#AlwaysuseDefaultTargeturl](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/AbstractAuthenticationTargetUrlRequestHandler.html#isAlwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl%28%29)

```
<beans:property name="authenticationSuccessHandler">
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler">
        <beans:property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/frame_design" />
        <beans:property name="alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl" value="true" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:property>
```

Comment: see the OP`s comment on my answer (my firs answer was the same like you have given) - he want some thing else

Comment: @Ralph Notice that I set the `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` property.  I think my answer differs in that respect.  It should always redirect to that url on login, regardless of if the user entered another url.  By default, Spring Security will go to the provided url, unless it cannot be resolved.

Comment: That is not the point: the question is: how to prevent from showing the login page to an already logged in user? - And I do not think that `alwaysUseDefaultTargetUrl` do this. - Am I right or is this a hidden feature?

Comment: @Ralph No your right, I just couldn't decipher the question.  OP didn't confirm intentions until after this answer.